# WPF Button to scroll Textbox

Tags: wpf, button, scroll, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox and a button.
Is there any easy way to make the textbox scroll down / up when i press the button? my guess is i have to use commands but im not 100% sure how commands work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is VerticalOffset property and ScrollToVerticalOffset method you can use:

```
richTB.ScrollToVerticalOffset(richTB.VerticalOffset - 15);
```